# Storyboard compiled but iOS cannot find it and crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

Whole build is compiling fine with some warnings and everything seems to work.

But when I run tests I get:

> 2015-05-13 10:38:52.450 InventorumNativeDevFast[38263:179686] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path '/Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4F58B740-983B-4E49-B3DC-4DD507DFF6DF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C49589F2-C9B5-4AEB-B12E-E57EE745C47C/InventorumNativeDevFast.app/Base.lproj/Inventory_iPad.storyboardc''

I narrowed logs down to compilation of this specific Storyboard.

```
mini:Base.lproj jenkins$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --target-device ipad --errors --warnings --notices --companion-strings-file de:/Users/jenkins/workspace/inventorum_frontend_ios_native_unit_tests_beta/InventorumNative/de.lproj/Inventory_iPad.strings --module Inventorum --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --output-partial-info-plist /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InventorumNative-adclekctloebjhfbehzjndtvdwbe/Build/Intermediates/InventorumNative.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/InventorumNativeDevFast.build/Inventory_iPad-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InventorumNative-adclekctloebjhfbehzjndtvdwbe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/InventorumNativeDevFast.app/Base.lproj /Users/jenkins/workspace/inventorum_frontend_ios_native_unit_tests_beta/InventorumNative/Base.lproj/Inventory_iPad.storyboard
nwi_state: registration failed (1000000)
2015-05-13 10:45:39.934 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[38344:184492] ***storageTaskManagerExistsWithIdentifier:withIdentifier failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4099.)" (The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.) UserInfo=0x7fb03493a480 {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; {
    NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.";
}
nwi_state: registration failed (1000000)
2015-05-13 10:45:42.639 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[38547:184520] ***storageTaskManagerExistsWithIdentifier:withIdentifier failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4099.)" (The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.) UserInfo=0x7fe69b72cd00 {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; {
    NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.";
}
nwi_state: registration failed (1000000)
2015-05-13 10:45:51.752 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[38359:184648] ***storageTaskManagerExistsWithIdentifier:withIdentifier failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4099.)" (The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.) UserInfo=0x7ff4f15182a0 {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; {
    NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.";
}
/* com.apple.ibtool.document.warnings */
/Users/jenkins/workspace/inventorum_frontend_ios_native_unit_tests_beta/InventorumNative/Base.lproj/Inventory_iPad.storyboard:ogr-LT-f0J: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width is not available on iOS versions prior to 8.0 [5]
/Users/jenkins/workspace/inventorum_frontend_ios_native_unit_tests_beta/InventorumNative/Base.lproj/Inventory_iPad.storyboard:GlE-Pp-88g: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width is not available on iOS versions prior to 8.0 [5]
/Users/jenkins/workspace/inventorum_frontend_ios_native_unit_tests_beta/InventorumNative/Base.lproj/Inventory_iPad.storyboard:b5N-m4-Eby: warning: Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width is not available on iOS versions prior to 8.0 [5]
mini:Base.lproj jenkins$
```

I don't have a clue what is wrong here... It works on my local machine, but on mac mini that is our build machine it fails.

I already cleaned project, removed derived data, restarted system.

Comment: Did you notice Inventory_iPad.storyboard**C** in your error message?

Comment: @Azat : it's a storyboard container, I believe there's nothing wrong with that

Comment: I checked and this file exists, it is compiled storyboard.

Comment: Maybe cleaning and rebuilding project will help? Or set storyboard files one more time?

Comment: I updated answer, all project was cleaned, derived data removed. I even restarted system.

Answer (score 5):

"Product -> Clean" should solve this problem. For me it worked.. Hope it help you as well..

Comment: Unfortunately did not, but I found a problem already. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This error appears when the bundle target isn't universal. So make sure the Targeted Device Family in the bundle's build settings is set to iPhone AND iPad.

reference question : [XCode no valid compiled storyboard at path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563618/xcode-no-valid-compiled-storyboard-at-path)

Comment: I already saw it but didn't connect it with my issue as I am building project for iPad only.

However, this helped a lot, thanks! I narrowed it down.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Britto's answer and checking more I narrowed it down.  I post it as answer so someone in future can find solution if he has the same bug.

**Solution**:

Check on which device tests are running, if you have targeted device only as iPad then it should run only on iPad.

---

I am building app only for iPad so targeted device is iPad only, somehow Jenkins is running tests on `iPhone` instead of `iPad`.

Now, I will check why, cause I forced him to run it on `iPad 2 (8.3)`...