# iPhone only app crashes on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I created and app targeted for iPhone, in Swift. When trying to run it on iPad it is crashing with:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path
'/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B7D84FA5-3A7D-4ED9-A7C0-DF7A808004FD/FluffyFly.app/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc''
```

My guess is that it is looking for an iPad storyboard, but I am not sure why.

I checked and the target is for iPhone only

[image: Xcode target configuration]

Any suggestion? Thank you

Edit: This is happening on device

Comment: Device or simulator?

Comment: On device. I tried to run directly from Xcode by connecting the computer to the device and I also created an Adhoc build distributed through hockeyapp.

Answer (score 2):

Do a clean and then install. If that doesn't work you may take a look here of that helps -

[XCode no valid compiled storyboard at path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563618/xcode-no-valid-compiled-storyboard-at-path)

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I had no luck