# Memory Issue in sqlite database iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, storyboard

I have used sqlite database in my app.I am doing CURD operation.I get data from json then i convert that data into arrays after that from arrays i insert the data into sqlite database.In my app when data can be upto more than 1000 records.When database is done then i get **memory warning**.

I have one function for Inserting data.It firstly check if data exists then update data else insert new record

`[[DBManager getSharedInstance]insertData:object`];

Function definition -

```
 (BOOL) insertData:(SubComponent *)subcomponent
{


    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if([self getSubComponentDataBySubclientClientInspectionid:subcomponent.componentid : subcomponent.componentsubclientid:subcomponent.componentClientid : subcomponent.componentinspectionid] != nil)
    {

        [self updateCompSubComponentDataBySubclientId:subcomponent];
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            if (sqlite3_exec(database, [@"PRAGMA CACHE_SIZE=500000;" UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"Successfully changed cache size");
            }
            else
                NSLog(@"Error: failed to set cache size with message %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            NSLog(@"inside isnert query");
            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"insert into subcomponent(subcomponentid,name,createddate,subclientid,clientid,cliententityid, inspectionid, initialstatus,componentclientname,componentsubclientname, checkedstatus) values (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%ld\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"2\")",subcomponent.componentid,subcomponent.componentName,subcomponent.componentcreateddate,subcomponent.componentsubclientid,subcomponent.componentClientid, subcomponent.componentEntityid,subcomponent.componentinspectionid,(long)subcomponent.componentStatus,subcomponent.componentClientName,subcomponent.componentSubclientName];
            NSLog(@"%@",insertSQL);
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                return YES;
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"REMASH DB ERROR %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
               // sqlite3_reset(statement);
                //sqlite3_close(database);
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                return NO;
            }
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**GET DATA FUNCTION**

```
- (SubComponent*) getSubComponentDataBySubclientClientInspectionid:(NSString*)componentid : (NSString *)subclientid : (NSString *)clientId : (NSString *)inspectionid
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from subcomponent where subcomponentid = \"%@\" and subclientid = \"%@\" and clientid = \"%@\" and inspectionid = \"%@\"",componentid,subclientid, clientId,inspectionid];
        NSLog(@"gghgh query is %@",querySQL);
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        SubComponent *resultArray = [[SubComponent alloc]init];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *component_id = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                resultArray.componentid = component_id;
                NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                  (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                resultArray.componentName = name;
                NSString *createddate = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                         (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                resultArray.componentcreateddate = createddate;
                NSString *subclientid = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                         (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                resultArray.componentsubclientid = subclientid;
                NSString *clientid = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                      (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
                resultArray.componentClientid = clientid;
                NSString *entityid = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                      (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
                resultArray.componentEntityid = entityid;
                NSString *inspectionid = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
                resultArray.componentinspectionid = inspectionid;
                NSString *clientName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8)];
                resultArray.componentClientName = clientName;
                NSString *subclientName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 9)];
                resultArray.componentSubclientName = subclientName;
//                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
//                sqlite3_close(database);
                return resultArray;
            }
            else
            {


//                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
//                sqlite3_close(database);
                return nil;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"error is %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
  //  sqlite3_reset(statement);
   // sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(database);

    return nil;
}
```

**Update Function**

```
-(void)updateCompSubComponentDataBySubclientId:(SubComponent *)subcomponent
{
    NSLog(@"inside update data");
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {


            if (sqlite3_exec(database, [@"PRAGMA CACHE_SIZE=500000;" UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"Successfully changed cache size");
            }
            else
                NSLog(@"Error: failed to set cache size with message %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));



        NSString *querySql=[NSString stringWithFormat:
                            @"UPDATE subcomponent SET name=\"%@\", createddate=\"%@\", cliententityid =\"%@\",componentclientname=\"%@\", componentsubclientname = \"%@\", checkedstatus = \"2\" where subcomponentid = \"%@\" and subclientid = \"%@\" and clientid = \"%@\" and inspectionid =\"%@\"",subcomponent.componentName,subcomponent.componentcreateddate, subcomponent.componentEntityid,subcomponent.componentClientName,subcomponent.componentSubclientName,subcomponent.componentid, subcomponent.componentsubclientid,subcomponent.componentClientid,subcomponent.componentinspectionid];
        const char *sql=[querySql UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(statement))
            {
                NSLog(@"REMASH Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
            else
            {
                //sqlite3_reset(statement);
                NSLog(@"Update done successfully!");
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"NOT OK");
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }


}
```

**PS**:Can somebody suggest whether use of sqlite_finilaize(),sqlite_close().sqlite_reset() is correct by seeing my code.Because memory is increasing.

Comment: Don't repost your questions.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score -2):

This is not a Database issue.

This issue is caused because Application doesn't have a storyboard for the device you are trying to run upon.

[XCode no valid compiled storyboard at path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563618/xcode-no-valid-compiled-storyboard-at-path)

Comment: This is not issue of story board because i am not getting this issue when data is lesss.check same link again here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563618/xcode-no-valid-compiled-storyboard-at-path/31965597#31965597

Comment: "There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path" error says clearly that it has nothing to do with DB.....

Comment: Please see the link i posted first.I told you clearly it is database issue.I am recving memory warnig in this case.

Comment: You didn't post early that you are getting memory warning also... Please upvote the answer.

Comment: Edited my answer.Help me out i will upvote the answer