# There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path in xcode 7.3 on ios9.3

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I'm writing application(iPad only app) for iPad(running iOS 9.3.3) its working well, but sometimes it get crashed by throwing,

```
2016-10-18 16:09:14.129 appName[239:23575] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/78FAE276-6B37-4A64-AB82-21F171D8E383/appName.app/PDSuperStory.storyboardc''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2149f91b 0x20c3ae17 0x2611ff71 0x84a88 0x13ef90 0xa6150 0x10c4dc 0x145a58 0xbd1b7f 0xbd1b6b 0xbd6655 0x21461b6d 0x21460067 0x213af229 0x213af015 0x2299fac9 0x25a83189 0x111698 0x21057873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Before this crash everything works fine no memory leaks showing in Instruments either. No solution working out after cleaning the project or re-installing application on device.

Any solution guys?

Comment: Why does the extension of your storyboard say `storyboardc` ? I think it should be `storyboard`

Comment: @dirtydanee  `storyboardc` is correct for a compiled storyboard.  (Open a .app package and check inside the resources folder.)

Comment: @PhillipMills that file is there in .app package

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563618/xcode-no-valid-compiled-storyboard-at-path

Comment: yes I checked that too, as I'm creating app for iPad family so Targeted Device family flag set to 2.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error till I just did Product>Clean Build Folder and now it seems all good.