# App crashes on iOS10 with exception “There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path”

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, ios10

**App is crashing on UIStoryboard Instantiate**

App is crashing on UIStoryboard Instantiate on shuffling app very frequently between foreground and background. Normally everything work fine, only when you shuffle app very frequently b/w foreground and background only then we have observed  this issue in iOS 10.0.

**We have checked and found following exception:-**

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/serialcode/XXX.app/AppLaunchStoryboard.storyboardc'

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Run the app
2. Play with app for some time (i.e navigate b/w different views),
   everything work fine.
3. Put app in background and then bring to foreground
4. Repeat 3 step 2-4 time
5. Try to navigate b/w different screen
6. App will crash
7. Exception: Terminating app due to uncaught exception
   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'There doesn't seem to be a
   valid compiled storyboard at path
   '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/serialcode/XXX.app/AppLaunchStoryboard.storyboardc

**It's crashing on following request:-**

```
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
```

**Note:-** In normal situation everything is working fine.(i.e if we don't suffle b/w foreground and background very frequently.)

Comment: In my case this solution working . http://stackoverflow.com/a/29563997/3901620

Comment: may i know what is your storyboard name ?

Comment: may be try with this Bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]

Comment: @dhanesh we have used multiple storyboard, so it depend upon the scenario which feature we are going to access.

Comment: Yes thats why its causing problem, as per my assumption your `storyboardName` become nil or may be deallocated and you got this issue.

Comment: Check your storyboard name is 'Main' or 'Storyboard' ?

Comment: The same request is working fine, if you keep app ideal for 5-10 sec.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's strange, but I solved it just delete 'Main storyboard file base name' key from Info.plist and added it again, after that this error never came again.